# Why is it showing "Int object is not interable" it isnt a interger

Tags: object, integer, iterable

```
username=input("Enter Username")
password=input("Password:")
for i in len(password):
    print("*")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. `len(password)` returns an integer; you are trying to iterate over it. Try `for i in range(len(password)):` instead of `for i in len(password):`.

Comment: Also, you should probably use [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) module if you want to prompt for a password in Python because it hides the characters typed. This code is python code, right? Please tag your question with [python] if it's python code.